# Python Dash Plotly Custom page_folder does not work with 404

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, custom-error-pages

I have a existing multipage dash application which needs to run on a docker and therefore I need a custom page_folder structure. Everything runs as it should, however the not_found_404.py does not work anymore.

Whenever an unknown page will be target, e.g. /bar, then the default 404 will be loaded. The custom 404 page will only be loaded if /404 will be targeted.

**File structure**

```
app.py
/modules
  foo.py
  not_found_404.py
  home.py
```

**app.py**

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import dash
from modules import home, foo

pages_folder = "modules"
app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, pages_folder=pages_folder, url_base_pathname="/super-app/") 
dash.register_page(home.__name__, path="/", layout=home.layout)  
dash.register_page(foo.__name__, path="/foo", layout=foo.layout)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Multi-page app with Dash Pages'),
    html.Div(
        [
            html.Div(
                dcc.Link(
                    f"{page['name']} - {page['path']}", href=page["relative_path"]
                )
            )
            for page in dash.page_registry.values() if page['path'] not in ['/404']
        ]
    ),
    dash.page_container
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

**home.py**

```
from dash import html

layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='This is our Home page'),
])
```

**foo.py**

```
from dash import html

layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='This is a page about: foo'),
])
```

**not_found_404.py**

```
from dash import html, dcc
from dash import register_page

register_page(__name__, path="/404",
              name="not_found_404", #explicit named
              title="404 Page not found",
              description="404 - no page found"
)

layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Access Denied: this is not a valid page name (yet)...'),
])
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work *anymore*. Does that mean it once worked? What happened in between it working and not working? Can you do something like [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-create-404-error-page-in-dash/42464/7)

Comment: @DeanMacGregor It worked before hosting it / moving it to the docker. Meaning that the pages_folder structure led to the missing 404 page... It seems that all pages/tabs can be moved, but not the not_found_404.py file.